# Change data binding value in ViewModel xamarin forms android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I have a binding set up:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using LoanApp2.Model;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using LoanApp2.Views;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace LoanApp2.ViewModel
{
    public class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // For data binding of activity indicator
        string actIndVal = "False";
        public string ActIndVal {
            get => actIndVal;
            set {
                if(actIndVal == value)
                {
                    return;
                } else
                {
                    actIndVal = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ActIndVal));
                }
            }
        }

        public static List<LoginBasicData> listLoginBasicData = new List<LoginBasicData>();

        public LoginViewModel()
        {
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged(string value)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(value));
        }
        public static async void VerifyClientID(string clientID)
        {
            // Start of HTTP Requests
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

The default value would be false, in in the class `VerifyClientID()`, I want to call the `ActIndVal` and change it to true so that the Activity Indicator will be visible. And call it again in the bottom part of the `VerifyClientID()` class so that I can change the value to false again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the property in the `ViewModel` won't work, you should change the value of `ActIndVal`  of the `ViewModel` which is your `BindContext`.

For example:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    LoginViewModel myViewModel;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
        this.BindingContext = myViewModel;
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myViewModel.ActIndVal = true;
        await myViewModel.VerifyClientID("clientID");
        myViewModel.ActIndVal = false;
    }
}

public class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // For data binding of activity indicator
    bool actIndVal = false;
    public bool ActIndVal
    {
        get => actIndVal;
        set
        {
            if (actIndVal == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                actIndVal = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ActIndVal));
            }
        }
    }

    public LoginViewModel()
    {
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(string value)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(value));
    }
    public async Task VerifyClientID(string clientID)
    {
        // Start of HTTP Requests
        await Task.Delay(3000);
    }
}
```

`myViewModel.ActIndVal` is the value you need to change because `Frame.IsVisible` is binding to this value. Changing the value of `ActIndVal` in your viewModel makes no sense.

I uploaded my sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/binding) and feel free to ask me any question.

Comment: `Changing the value of ActIndVal in your viewModel makes no sense` -- unless Command is used and the ViewModel's method is bound to the Command.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Also now it gives an error saying that you cannot await void

Comment: @e700867 See my code about method `VerifyClientID` : `public async Task VerifyClientID(string clientID)`, change the return value to a Task.

Answer (score 0):

first of all this should be a boolean to avoid casting issues

```
private bool actIndVal;
    public bool ActIndVal {
        get => actIndVal;
        set {
            if(actIndVal == value)
            {
                return;
            } else
            {
                actIndVal = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ActIndVal));
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in your method change the values:

```
        public async Task VerifyClientID(string clientID)
        {
            ActIndVal= true;
            //API CALL CODE
            ActIndVal= false;
        }
```

Then just bind this to your Indicator

```
<ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding ActIndVal}" IsVisible="{Binding ActIndVal}" ....
```

Comment: I actually already tried the ActIndVal = true but it says "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'LoginViewModel.ActIndVal'"

Comment: It's because `VerifyClientID` is static and the method does not need to static once you change that it should work!

Comment: it still doesn't work. My method is now ```public async void VerifyClientID(string clientID)```

Comment: What does it say now? And is your binding context set properly?

Comment: It doesn't say anything it just doesn't show. This is how my binding is: ```<Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" BackgroundColor="White" Margin="0" CornerRadius="30" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" HasShadow="True" Padding="20" x:Name="ActIndXAML" IsVisible="{Binding ActIndVal}">
                <StackLayout>
                    <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" BackgroundColor="White" Color="#62bef0" />
                    <Label Text="Loading..."/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>```